# docker machine: getsockopt no route to host

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

I set up docker private registry with Nexus 3.0.2 OSS on windows 2012 server as below,

[docker_repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5OJI.png)

there is a docker machines (version 0.8.0) installed on VirtualBox through Docker tools (v1.12.0) for windows (windows 8.1). I added the repository connector url to insecureRegistry in config.json file to allow insecure connection. It always returns "no route to host" error when trying to login to the Nexus docker registry. but it gets responds if using curl to test the connector.

Could someone please advise me how to fix it up as I am a novice to docker?

[docker_registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKiBO.png)